# Why SVG pattern is not drawn by full canvas repeatly?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code:

```
function CrossTemplate(gridOptions, canvas) {

  const config = {color: '#000000', gridSize: 4, gridPadding: 0, strokeStyle: "#00000"};
  const bw = canvas.width;
  const bh = canvas.width;
  const p = 0;
  const cw = bw + p * 2 + 1;
  const ch = bh + p * 2 + 1;

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = ch;
  canvas.width = cw;

  if (!context) throw Error('Canvas context error');

  for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
  }

  for (var x = 1; x <= bh; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = config.strokeStyle;
  context.stroke();

  return canvas;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2mg8dxs/12/

I wonder, why I dont see pattern canvas, where I did mistake?

I use parent context:

```
const context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
context2.fillStyle = context.createPattern(canvas, 'repeat');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the creation of the pattern canvas inside the function that you defined and then return the canvas in the end. I think it makes it more transparent what happens. I have a hard time reading your code, but this seams to work.

And then you also missed the `fillRect()` in the end.

```js
function CrossTemplate(gridOptions) {

  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  canvas.width = 512;
  canvas.height = 512;

  const config = {
    color: '#000000',
    gridSize: 4,
    gridPadding: 0,
    strokeStyle: "#00000"
  };
  const bw = canvas.width;
  const bh = canvas.width;
  const p = 0;
  const cw = bw + p * 2 + 1;
  const ch = bh + p * 2 + 1;

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = ch;
  canvas.width = cw;

  if (!context) throw Error('Canvas context error');

  for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
  }

  for (var x = 1; x <= bh; x += config.gridSize) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = config.strokeStyle;
  context.stroke();

  return canvas;
}

const canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
canvas2.width = 1024;
canvas2.height = 1024;

let canvas = CrossTemplate({
  lineWidth: 1,
  b: 24,
  k: -1,
  strokeStyle: '#215cff',
  lineCap: 'square'
});

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
context2.fillStyle = context.createPattern(canvas, 'repeat');
context2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, how to fix issue when I have two lines in intersection, I need to fill whole square by lines

Comment: I have tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/k2mg8dxs/24/